# VBA: Stop recursive Function re-opening workbook after workbook close

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to check if the read-only workbook a user is viewing has been updated:

```
Function NewVersion() As Boolean

    If a <> b Then Flag = True: Exit Function

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "NewVersion"

End Function
```

However, whenever I close the workbook, it reopens (presumably as NewVersion is loaded into memory and set to run in 5sec?)

How can I prevent this happening?

I've tried a variety of things but no luck so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a public variable to keep track of the next time that your macro should fire and cancel if using the Schedule parameter of Application.OnTime.

```
Public ScheduledTime As Date

Function NewVersion() As Boolean
    ScheduledTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Application.OnTime ScheduledTime, "NewVersion"

End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime ScheduledTime, "NewVersion", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```